# Get assembly's LogLevel

Tags: .net, logging, .net-core

Most - if not all - of the Microsoft assemblies' logging can be configured, e.g.:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Critical",
    "Microsoft": "Information",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Warning"
  }
}
```

but how to implement it for custom assemblies? I could just check the configuration for an entry containing the executing assembly's name, but I'm pretty sure there already is an "out-of-the-box" solution and no need to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

I totally misunderstood the idea of it! These are filters setting a minimum log level! So my question is answered, thank you!